# looking for javascript - json - load on demand combo box

Tags: jquery, json

I have seen Flexbox (http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox) which appears quite nice but I don't think it is dynamic in nature where as someone types it will go back to the server to get only those results that start with the typed in text.

I was looking at a telerik combobox which is nice but it requires a bunch of web.config entries which I am trying to avoid.

Anyone know of any other client based type ahead combo boxes?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting on [jQuery::Automplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox), all questions with combos/autocomplete is closed for me.